# I am trying to use openid for my website. Can someone please point me to a asp.net mvc working sample that uses openid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, openid, dotnetopenauth

Due to lack to time i cannot dig google and get information about openid and then implement it. Can someone please point me to a working asp.net sample that explains how openid works with asp.net mvc. Thanks.

Comment: at some point Jeff was thinking about releasing code for SO...but I guess he is still refactoring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is c# library to help you to do this called dotnetOpenAuth:

http://dotnetopenauth.net:8000/

This is the same as used by Stackoverflow

Comment: It also includes an MVC sample.